# MariaDB not optimizing query

Tags: performance, join, mariadb

first question here ever, so be nice :-)

I used to use MySQL on all of my servers and since Cent OS 7 now comes with MariaDB instea, I gave it a try. All seems to be good except for one query, which MySQL performs in milliseconds and MariaDB takes seconds :(

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT id, date_start FROM matches
    WHERE matches.type =5409
    AND matches.status =10
    AND matches.date_start >=  '2016-02-01'
    AND matches.date_start <=  '2016-02-08'
) AS tmp
INNER JOIN seat ON tmp.id = seat.match_id
```

The table seat has 5.4 million entries, matches has a third of that. For every match played there are 3 seats.

Now MySQL cleverly derives the tmp table first and then joins on the mere 112 matches found for the given time frame:

```
id select_type  table      type possible_keys key      len  ref    rows     Extra
1  PRIMARY      <derived2> ALL   NULL         NULL     NULL NULL   112  
1  PRIMARY      seat       ref  match_id      match_id 8    tmp.id 3    
2  DERIVED      matches    ALL  NULL          NULL     NULL NULL   1919638  Using where
```

MariaDB on the other hand does the JOIN first on the whole matches table. Not so smart for 5 million entries:

```
id select_type  table   type   possible_keys key     len  ref           rows    Extra
1  SIMPLE       seat    ALL    match_id      NULL    NULL NULL          5462345 
1  SIMPLE       matches eq_ref PRIMARY       PRIMARY 8    seat.match_id 1       Using where
```

match_id is a key in the seat table.

I tried different approaches and nothing worked. I don't want to give up on MariaDB yet, because I read that and also noticed myself that it's somewhat faster on other queries. But this is actually a show stopper...

So any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For `matches`:

```
INDEX(type, status, date_start)
```

will speed up both MySQL and MariaDB.  (`type` and `status` can be swapped, but `date_start` needs to be third.)

The reason for the difference is that MySQL is ahead of MariaDB on certain optimizations, and you hit one such.